# Empty message problem with discord.js embeds

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm having some problems with discord embed

I have 3 embeds: embed1, embed2, embed3 but when i try to send an embed with a message with this code: `message.channel.send({embed1})`

I get this error:

> (node:24120) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message

Comment: So is `embed1` empty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is cause in ES6 without adding the definer in an object. The varible's name is now the definer.
Example:

```js
    message.channel.send({embed1});
    //Get's translated to: 
    message.channel.send({embed1:embed1});
```

Since all objects need an definer and a value. ES6 just shortens it.

So your `message.channel.send({embed1});` sets the definer to `embed1`
Which then `embed` is undefined, and Discord.js doesn't know where the message is as it looks for the definer `embed` not `embed1`. Therefore it thinks it has no message or embed to send, **Hence the empty message error**

To upload your embed with your current code you'll need `message.channel.send({embed:embed1});`;

Answer (score 3):

I had to do:

```
    message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] })
```

Comment: This works as of v13.6.0